# I've updated CF9 mail server settings but my application is still trying to use the old mail server

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfmail

We changed our exchange mail server so I've update the mail server in CF9 admin settings. I've verified that it can connect to the new server and it can. But when I test sending an email it keeps failing because it is trying to connect to the old mail server. When I look in the mail.log it clearly lists the old server as the SMTP host it is trying to connect to and it fails.

Where else could CF9 be pulling the old mail server from?
Are there other places where my predecessor could have coded in the old mail server?

I've looked in various .cfm files for any reference to the old exchange server but have found none.

Thanks,
Dan

Ok so what I ended up doing was to actually hard code the new server into the one location we are actually using a cfmail tag. That fixed it. Not much of a chance this app will ever do anything other than this so should be fine.

Dan

Comment: Check the CFMAIL tags, themselves.  You can specify server settings as tag attributes.

Comment: Was the `CFMAIL` tag referencing an application or session variable? Or was it not defining the server attribute at all?  Do you have more than one instance of the CF server running on the server? If so, it's possible you updated a different instance than the one running your application.

Comment: The CFMAIL tag was not defining the server. I updated it to define the server which caused it to override the server setup in CF9 Admin mail settings. This has fixed my problem. This app has only once simple task which is to send these emails. All other functions have been moved to another server.